# Eclipse Hadoop HDFS Exception

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I am new in Handoop and I try to star my first program.

In first case I use Eclipse: Run -> Run Configuration -> Program Arguments -> input output , both file was in my computer and my program works fine.

But when I try change input to hdfs it dont work. I use Eclipse: Run -> Run Configuration -> Program Argument ->hdfs://localhost:50070 output

I try change input adress (hdfs://127.0.1.1:50070,hdfs://pds-hadoop:50070, ) but it give same mistake all the time :

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "pds-hadoop/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":50070;

I dont know where is problem and I dont understood this mistake. My HDFS works fine, it is at localhost:50070 and I put all files to HDFS.

I found core-site.xml where is :

```
<configuration>    <property>        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>    
</property> <property>        <name>io.native.lib.available</name>        <value>false</value>    
</property></configuration>
```

I try to change `<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>` to `<value>hdfs://localhost:50070</value>` and now absolutly nothing dont work. Where is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve it. Problem was that localhost:50070 was not deafult way, but it was localhost:9000. What mean that, corect way is Run -> Run Configuration -> Program Argument ->hdfs://localhost:9000/ output